# Performing Text Lookup with GUID as an input in Kingswaysoft Dynamics 365 Toolkit

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, data-migration, dataverse, kingswaysoft

In Kingswaysoft's Dynamics 365 Integration Toolkit, is there any way to lookup/match CRM  **ownerid** GUID from source table to a custom column in destination's user entity?

**My problem**

For some reason, I have to perform a text lookup from source entity's **ownerid** field to destination user entity's **new_legacyuserid** custom column that holds user GUIDs from the source system. But it seems like the Text Lookup Editor doesn't match source **ownerid** with **new_legacyuserid** column in the destination user entity, but matches if I pass  **owneridname** column as an input.

I have pre populated the **new_legacyuserid** with a single GUID from the source as a fallback user indication and this column is null for all other records. So all the records' **ownerid** should fallback to the default user.

Now, when I pass **ownerid** as an input to the Text Lookup (please see the image below) the package fails with the following error:

> {"error":{"code":"0x80040217","message":"systemuser With Id =
> be33cd29-671b-e511-80ce-005056ae320c Does Not Exist"}}

However, to test differently, when I pass **owneridname** as an input to the TextLookup, the package runs successfully and all the two records ownership falls back to the default destination user.

I want to perform the same match using **ownerid** and not **owneridname**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any way to use user GUID (OwnerId in this case) in the Text Lookup Editor. It seems that when GUID is passed as an input, the KWS adapter doesn't look at the Text Lookup Editor at all.

One of my colleague tried this workaround and this worked. You can try that if your source CRM is on-premises.

- Create a derived column in SQL select statement (OwnerIdString) to
  store GUID as a string
- Use OwnerIdString column as input

Example:

> SELECT task.*, **convert(VARCHAR(36), ownerid) AS OwnerIdString** FROM task

This will force the Kingswaysoft adapter to do a Text Lookup based on GUID.